# Subdomains in rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, subdomain, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm trying to set up my rails 4.1 app works with more than one sub domain, I see the [Rails Casts - #221](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3), but I have any problems:

My domain in production is: `transporte.adm.br` *nothing to show yet!
Because it have 2 domains `adm.br`, I can't do this work.

My /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost
::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
127.0.0.1   transporte.adm.br
127.0.0.1   *.transporte.adm.br
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/' => 'login#index', :constraints => { :subdomain => /\bsecure\b/ }

  resources :client
  constraints(Subdomain) do
    get '/' => 'client#index'
  end

  root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

url_helper:

```
 module UrlHelper
  def with_subdomain(subdomain)
    subdomain = (subdomain || '')
    subdomain += '.' unless subdomain.empty?
    [subdomain, request.domain(2), request.port_string].join
  end

  def url_for(options = nil)
    if options.kind_of?(Hash) && options.has_key?(:subdomain)
      options[:host] = with_subdomain(options.delete(:subdomain))
    end
    super
  end
end
```

subdomain.rb:

```
class Subdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain(2).present? && request.subdomain(2) != 'www'
  end
end
```

What I trying to do is: When I access the route `secure.transporte.adm.br` => 'login#index' and when I access any other subdomain route to => 'client#index' without subdomain to => 'home#index'

With `lvh.me:3000` Works fine, but when I try with my domain `transporte.adm.br` not!
When I access any route with transporte.adm.br nothing happen...

Thanks for all!

Comment: cause your domain is sub-subdomain, you can setup your dns and on your `routes.rb` you could make root always point to `transporrte.adm.abr` looks like `root :to => 'home#index', :subdomain => 'transporte'`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I can't to do this, in production my full domain is 'transporte.adm.br'... But you said about configure my DNS... how I do this? Any tutorial/web site/blog for I see ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is tell Rails the length of your TLD.

add this to your correct environment (`config/environments/production.rb` most likely)

`config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 2`

and then the request.subdomain should return the correct parts for you automatically